# MadvertiseView failed to instantiate

Tags: android, xml, view, admob, ads

I want to use Madvertise instead of AdMob as advertising platform, but I keep getting the following error: de.madvertise.android.sdk.MadvertiseView failed to instantiate.

here's my xml layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:mad="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.celticwolf.alex"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_dimback"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adsContainer" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeFeedback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adsContainer"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/tvBeerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/country"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/blanktwo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="-2.5"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/beername"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/glassfull1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llButtonHorizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/glassfull" />
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llButtonHorizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blanktwo" /><LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adsContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

   <de.madvertise.android.sdk.MadvertiseView
        android:id="@+id/madad"
        android:layout_width="320dip"
        android:layout_height="53dip"
        mad:bannerType="mma"
        mad:placement_type="inline"/>
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/country_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"/>
 </LinearLayout>   

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llButtonHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bBeer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/custombeer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNoBeer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:background="@drawable/customnobeer" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/glassfull2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llButtonHorizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/glassfullrigth" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIsBeer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeFeedback"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="-2.5"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text="@string/check"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the complete error log:

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-07-08 01:37:17.733
!MESSAGE de.madvertise.android.sdk.MadvertiseView failed to instantiate.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.madvertise.android.sdk.MadvertiseUtil.checkForBrowserDeclaration(MadvertiseUtil.java:526)
    at de.madvertise.android.sdk.MadvertiseView.<init>(MadvertiseView.java:201)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:385)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2746)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Here is the manifest.

```
    <uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
         />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/bonbicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" 
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.celticwolf.alex.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Game"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.celticwolf.alex.GAME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/about" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.celticwolf.alex.ABOUT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".SendBrand"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/sendbeerbrand" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.celticwolf.alex.SENDBRAND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HighscoreView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/txthighscore" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.celticwolf.alex.HIGHSCOREVIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
        <activity android:name=".ShareOnFacebook" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>

   <!-- open external urls -->
        <activity android:name="de.madvertise.android.sdk.MadvertiseActivity" />

        <!-- Setup your site token. For tests, use 'TestTokn'-->
        <meta-data android:value="TestTokn" android:name="madvertise_site_token" />

        <!-- Mraid TestSuite -->
        <activity android:name="android.app.Activity" />
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        </application>

       <instrumentation android:targetPackage="de.madvertise.test" android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" />

</manifest>
```

Here's how the XML Editor in Eclipse looks, but when I run it it doesn't show any ads:
[image]

I hope anybody can help  and thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you setup your manifest correctly?

Comment: Yep. Pretty much just as in the Tutorial...

Comment: Why does you have android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" in your manifest if you are no longer using Admob?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error inside Eclipse. Ie Eclipse can't render the MadvertiseView. This is an Eclipse problem and not an Android problem. Does your app run? I suspect it does.

Comment: yeey... Eclipse+XML sucks massive... Do you know how I can solve this?  As you said, the app runs but It doesn't show any ads. I've includet a picture on top how it looks in the XML View in Eclipse.

Comment: Well, you could use AndroidStudio which is a customised IntelliJ and is the new option from the Android dev team. I use IntelliJ and it is great for Android development. You may not be getting any ads because there are none to serve, you would need to check your logs and the Madvertise doco for this.

Comment: Thanks! I guess thats the problem... I'm getting  Response 204 in the log which means "Everything ok, but no ads to serve". Looks like this is a common problem at Madvertise since they don't have that many ads to serve. I thought that the Test_Token would always show some pseudo Ads, which isnt the case..